# Escaping percent signs in Lua Sqlite3 Prepare Statement

Tags: sqlite, lua

I have a statement:

(db is a sqlite3 instance)

```
local stmt = db:prepare("SELECT id, name FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%?%'")
if stmt:bind_values("test") == sqlite3.OK then 
   ....
end
```

However, I get this error:

```
Incorrect number of parameters to bind (1 given, 0 to bind)
```

It seems it is not seeing the ? as a parameter.  I have tried all kinds of escaping from %% for the percent signs to \ and \\ and beyond...driving me crazy.

Anyone know how to fix this?  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put parameters inside quotes:

```
correct:     SELECT ... WHERE foo = ?
incorrect:   SELECT ... WHERE foo = '?'
```

With the quotes, it's just a string that contains a question mark. Without the quotes, it's a placeholder.

You'll have to build up the LIKE in pieces, e.g.

```
... WHERE foo LIKE '%' || ? || '%'
```